# Localized date and time in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

*This question is not referred to generic Java, but to Codename One only.*

I tried:

```
SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.FULL, SimpleDateFormat.FULL).format(new Date());
```

that returns (both on Simulator and on Android):

`Sun Jan 13 14:41:35 CET 2019`

How can I get a localized version of date and time? I mean localized automatically, without the need that I specify the format for each locale.

For example, when I run the app on an Italian smartphone, I expect an equivalent string like:

`13 gennaio 2019, 14:41:35`

If it's possible, without the name of the day of week and without "CET".

I noted that `(SimpleDateFormat.FULL, SimpleDateFormat.FULL)` or `(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT, SimpleDateFormat.SHORT)` return the same string in this example.

Comment: Update: on iPhone, it shows `13 January 2019` without the time. Instead I need the time and possibly the same string on Android, iPhone and web-app.

Comment: You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. See `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…`.  If Codename One does not support Java 8 or later, then learn about the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `L10NManager` which includes formatters for date/time e.g.:

```
String asString = L10NManager.getInstance().formatDateLongStyle(date);
```

Comment: Thank you, `L10NManager.getInstance().formatDateTimeMedium(new Date());` solves my problem. I noted that there are little differences between the returned strings on Android, iPhone and web-app. For example, Android returns `14 gen 2019 11:20:33 AM`, iPhone returns `14 Jan 2019 at 11:15:20`, while the web-app on Android Chrome returns `14/1/2019, 11:22:17`.

Comment: This uses the OS native API's for the formatting on Android/iOS. I'm not sure if it's implemented properly in the web version. Since the OS native API's will produce different results you would see a difference.